# @media print div: How to solve overlapping page text on pages?

Tags: html, css

I found some answers for this question, but that doesn't apply for my css.
Currently i want to print into A4 landscape. I create each div as a page, which has css and print css as follow:

```
.page {
    background-color: #FFF;
    margin: 10pt 0pt 10pt 0pt;
    width: 800pt;
    height: 600pt;
    padding: 22pt;
}
```

and

```
@media print {
    .page {
        height: 210mm;
        width: 297mm;
        size: A4;
        bottom: 3em;
    }
```

JSfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/vc5L29m9/ 
but the divs in each pages overlapping each others and tend to move to the top.
What css am i missing from the div?

Comment: [size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page/size) should be set on [@page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page). Not the class `.page` . You should also probably recreate an example. Hard to guess.

Comment: Please don't post credentials or emails. Things around here get indexed real fast. You should narrow down the problem and post the code here or on a code testing environment. ex: jsfiddle or codepen.

Comment: added jsfiddle, there is one print button at the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Move the [size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page/size) property to [@page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page) rule.
- Add `size: landscape`.
- Use the [page-break-after](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-after) property to control page breaks after every `page` class.

Also added a class to hide elements on print. Do the same for things you don't need. (print button)

Here is the [updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vc5L29m9/3/)

#### CSS

```
@page {
  size: landscape;
}

@media print {
  .page {
    page-break-after: always
  }
  .no-print {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: your updated one still have the table header placed on the top of the page https://leejangkoo-gmail.tinytake.com/sf/OTgyMTY1XzQwODY5NzU. That's tricky one i couldn't know why.

Comment: Thats tricky. Use `thead {display: table-row-group}` in your print rule. That should fix it. I guess browsers repeat thead nodes everytime when they print.

Comment: You are genius @Ankith